# How to fix click event on fast miltiple clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, events

I'm trying when clicking on a row to show and hide the side panel.

**Example:** Click some row and the side panel must be visible. If you click the same row, the side panel must be hidden, but if you click on another row, the side panel must to hide for short time and then show again.

The problem is if you click fast multiple times the row/rows, the slide effect of the side panel continues event I'm not clicking. What do I need to change ?

Thanks!

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('.table tr').hover(tableRowHover);

function tableRowHover() {
  $(this).find('td > div').toggleClass('hovered');
}

  $('.details').on('click', function () {

    var tableData = $(this).find('td > div');
    var selected = $(tableData).hasClass("bordered");
    var paneVisible = $('#detailsPane').is(":visible");

    $(".details > td > div").removeClass("bordered");

    if (!selected) {
      $(tableData).addClass("bordered");
      $('#detailsPane')
        .hide(0, "slide", { direction: "left" })
        .delay(100)
        .show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 800);
    } else if (selected && paneVisible) {
      $('#detailsPane').hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 800);
    }

  });
});
```

```css
 .table {
    min-width: 1200px;
    width: 100%;
}

.table thead th {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
}

.table td {
    padding: 10px 0 0 !important;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
}

.table td > div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 52px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 7px 3px 7px rgba(65, 78, 121, .06);
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.table td:first-child > div {
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}

.table td:last-child > div {
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}

.table td > div.hovered {
    background-color: #baeb8d;
    border-top: 1px solid #93e04c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #93e04c;
}

.table td:first-child > div.hovered,
.table td:first-child > div.bordered {
    border-left: 1px solid #93e04c;
}

.table td:last-child > div.hovered,
.table td:last-child > div.bordered {
    border-right: 1px solid #93e04c;
}

.table td > div.bordered {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #93e04c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #93e04c;
}

.pane {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 50px 40px;
    background-color: #baeb8d;
    box-shadow: 0 0 9px rgba(65, 78, 121, 0.05);
    z-index: 2200;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>TABLE HEADING</th>
        <th>TABLE HEADING</th>
        <th>TABLE HEADING</th>
        <th>TABLE HEADING</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="details">
      <td>
        <div>
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Data 1</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Data 1</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Data 1</div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="details">
      <td>
        <div>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Data 2</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Data 2</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Data 2</div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="details">
      <td>
        <div>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Data 3</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Data 3</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Data 3</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="pane hidden" id="detailsPane"></div>
```

Comment: what have you tried? you could set a flag during transition to prevent the callback from running when you don't want it to

Comment: If you've started an animation, you can use `.stop()` to stop it if you need to do something else.

Comment: I have tried this with `.stop()`, but it did not solve my problem or maybe I'm wrong somewhere